# How to output a partial or a number from a mataching in grep or ack

Tags: linux, grep, sorting, ack

I have a text file `demo.txt` like below.

```
This is a line with id (9)
This (8) is another line with id
(10) This is a line with id too
11 This line does nothing
```

The file has some lines with id scattered randomly. The id pattern is number with parenthesis.

My job is to find the largest id in this file so that I know what the next id is when adding a new line.

My previous work

```
ack-grep demo.txt -o --match '\(\d+\)' | sort -r | head -n 1
```

The result is `(9)` but not `(10)` as my expectation. I think the reason is `sort` regards the output as text because they have parenthesis.

The question is: How can I output only the number from `ack` or `grep` for later sorting but still matching the pattern(parenthesis in my example)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmm, no 'ack' on my system to test with. Is it this program? http://betterthangrep.com/install/

Comment: @Hennes, yes, it's that program. And in Ubuntu the name is `act-grep`. There is a package `apt-get install ack-grep`. I myself found `act` more stable than `grep`.

Comment: @BillyChan: You mean `ack-grep` and `ack`, not `act-grep` and `act`.  And how do you mean that ack is more stable than grep?  I'm the author of ack and I certainly wouldn't make such a claim.

Comment: @AndyLester, thanks for your nice work on `ack`. I used `grep` before but sometimes met weird errors, then I switched to `ack` and such errors disappeared. So I added such claim on my notes but really could not recall the cases for the errors.

Comment: ack and grep behave differently.  For one, ack won't look in binary files unless you very specifically ask it to, so maybe the errors you were getting were warnings about searching binary data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` can't be used to output parts of a match, but why not get rid of the parentheses?

This works for GNU `grep`:

```
grep -P '\(\d+\)' -o demo.txt | sed 's/[()]//g' | sort -nr | head -n1
```

The following also work for BSD `grep`, which you can use on OS X, for example:

```
grep -E '\([[:digit:]]+\)' -o demo.txt | …    
grep -E '\([0-9]+\)' -o demo.txt | …
```

To get the result we want, we add the `-n` argument to `sort` to sort numerically, which gives you `10` as the first result.

Comment: For completeness sake (though I prefer default installed packages over extra installed perl scripts): `./ack-grep demo.txt -o --match '\(\d+\)' |  sed 's/[()]//g' | sort -nr | head -n 1`   (Using slhk's sort and sed).

Comment: Yes, I figured I'd use the default `grep` since not everyone might have `ack-grep`, but the first command can easily be replaced of course.

Comment: slhck, The answer works perfectly. The sed command is so smart. Thanks a lot! @Hennes, thank you too!